# Javascript. How to return the questions and correct answers to a Math.random

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm fairly new to javascript and am having an issue. I found this code snippet and am trying to display the question, user answer, and correct answer from ask() after the user inputs their answers from all the questions. I've tried a for loop to display each index, but that simply returns true or false.

Here's the code:

```
<script>
    function ask() {
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        var op = ["*", "+", "/", "-"][Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
        return prompt("How much is " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?") == eval( a + op + b);
    }

    var questions = [ask(), ask(), ask(), ask(), ask()],
        total = questions.length,
        correct = questions.filter(Boolean).length;


    alert( "You got "+correct+"/"+total+" correctly");
</script>
```

And you can test the current code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/on1nnzpj/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an object to return from the ask() function.

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mdsctat0/1/)

```
function ask() {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var op = ["*", "+", "/", "-"][Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];

    return {
            question : "How much is " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?",
            ansGiven: prompt("How much is " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?"),
            ansCorrect : eval( a + op + b),
            get isCorrect(){return this.ansGiven == this.ansCorrect}
           };
}

var questions = [ask(), ask(), ask(), ask(), ask()],
    total = questions.length,
    correct = questions.filter(function(ans){return ans.isCorrect}).length;

alert( "You got "+correct+"/"+total+" correctly");
questions.forEach(function(q, i){
    alert("Question " +(i+1)+ " : " + q.question 
    + "\nAnswer: " + q.ansGiven 
    + "\nCorrect Answer: " + q.ansCorrect 
    + "\n You were " + ((q.isCorrect)?"Correct!":"Wrong!"));
});
```

Comment: Nice. Where would you put an if else statement showing if you were correct. So at the bottom it would say: You were correct! or: You were wrong!

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/on1nnzpj/1/

Return a function from `ask()` and then compare the answer given with the correct answer:

```
function ask() {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var op = ["*", "+", "/", "-"][Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
    return new function() { this.op = op; this.ans = prompt("How much is " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?"); this.cor = eval( a + op + b); this.suc = this.ans == this.cor};
}

function isCorrect(element){
    return element.suc;
}

var questions = [ask(), ask(), ask(), ask(), ask()],
    total = questions.length;
    console.log(questions); 
    var correct = questions.filter(isCorrect).length;


alert( "You got "+correct+"/"+total+" correctly");
function alertQ(elem){
    if (!elem.suc){
        alert ("Your answer was: " + elem.ans + " correct answer was: " + elem.cor);
    }
}
questions.forEach(alertQ);
```

**Update**

Change

```
return new function() { this.op = op; this.ans = prompt("How much is " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?"); this.cor = eval( a + op + b); this.suc = this.ans == this.cor};
```

to this to add the question:

```
return new function() { this.op = op; this.q = "How much is " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?"; this.ans = prompt(this.q); this.cor = eval( a + op + b); this.suc = this.ans == this.cor};
```

and modify the alertQ:

Your answer for question 1: 5 *4 was 20. That was correct!

```
function alertQ(elem, index){
    var c = elem.cor ? " That was correct!" : " That was incorrect!"
    alert ("Your answer for question " + (index + 1) + ": " + elem.q + " was: " + elem.ans + c);
}
```

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to add which question it was? Like: Your answer for question 1: 5 *4 was 20. That was correct! Alert: Your answer for question 2: 2/1 was 1. That was incorrect.